How to repair flashing between stucco and brick chimney?
The flashing that transitions from my stucco wall to my brick chimney appears to be separating from the chimney. This separation is occurring across the entire height of the chimney and not just in one area.
What would be the proper process to repair this?


fill with UV resistant silicone

@Traveler on the right side where the flashing meets the chimney?

Yes, where the cracks are
